# Portable way (linux & Windows) to have a file only modifiable by 1 process and not others in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, winapi

I'm looking for a portable way (linux & Windows) to have a file only modifiable by 1 process and not others in C/C++.

The full requirement is that I want to keep a file only modifiable by 1 running process, as the others should only be able to read it.

The difficulty is that this process uses a vendor library that will fopen/fclose the file many times during its life (tens of seconds).

Thanks

Comment: Why not set the default file property to read only and then have the process change it to read+write whenever it wants to change that file.

Comment: I doubt very much you can do this without either modifying the vendor library, or if at all possible, add some global types of locks. A redesign of the whole idea, using a different solution may also work. [user986959's idea won't work, since once you change the mode, all others are allowed in too...]

Comment: Are all the processes in your control?

Comment: Linux only has advisory locks, and an outright weak permissions system, so you're SOL there. On Windows it might just work out of the box (breaks if `fopen("w")` passes `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`, but the default option is safe)

Comment: I think you will need to provide more details about how you are interacting with the vendor library and how it opens the file. You will have to add a locking function external to the library. Does it's api allow you to choose wether the file is opened read/write or read only? Can you intercept the opening of the file?

Comment: @MSalters
I don't know this behaviour. I guess that I have to dig in the fopen API.

Comment: @user986959 I cannot set it to read only, since the vendor library opens, read/writes and closes the file many times

Comment: @David
Yes, all the processes are in our control. Are you thinking to mutex, or semaphore creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the "inter process communications"

For instance ,on Windows you could use following code, which makes sure that only one process would be able to write into this file.

```
    int WriteToFile()
    {
         HANDLE _mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, L"__File_Write__");
         if(GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) 
         {
             return -1;
         }
         else
         {
             //write to file
             return 0;
         }
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like this, but I thought it is not easily portable, unless I find a way to wrap Linux and Windows codes.
Thanks for the detail however.

Comment: There are plenty of threading libraries that abstract these details away